# enable/disable button on a table on selection of dropdown using ng-options not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with a dropdown selection in each row, I wanted to make an upload button (to work) only when the the drop down status is done. Right now its not working properly
[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/m55ow6re/20/)

```
  <body ng-app='saapp', ng-controller = "homeCtrl">
<body>
<table>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="test in tests ">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{test}}</td>
    <td style="color:red"> pending</td>
    <td><font size="2" color="red"></font>
      <select ng-model="checkStatus" ng-init="checkStatus='NotDone'", ng-options="status.sta as status.name for status in status" ng-change="changePayStatus(checkStatus)"></select>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-2">
      <P>
<button type="button" ng-show="!pictureEditor" ng-click="pictureEditor = true" ng-disabled="enableUpload" class="btn-primary btn-u-xs">Upload </button>
<div ng-show="pictureEditor">
 <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFile(this.files)"/>
<div ng-show="pictureEditor" class="input-group"><span class="input-group-btn">

<button ng-click="saveDiagnosticReport(test, appointmentDetails); pictureEditor = false " class="btn btn-default">Save &nbsp;<i class="input-save fa fa-check-square"></i></button>
<button ng-click="pictureEditor = false" class="btn btn-default">Back &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-undo"></i></button></span></div>
        </div>
      </P>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
</body>
```

angular controller

```
    var app = angular.module('saapp',[ ]);
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.tests = ["A", "B", "C"] 
 $scope.status = [{name :"Done", sta : 1}, {name : "NotDone", sta : 0}];
   $scope.enableUpload = 1;
 $scope.changePayStatus = function(status) {
          console.log(status);
            if(status == '1') {
                $scope.enableUpload = 0;
            }
            else if(status == "0") {
                $scope.enableUpload = 1;

            }
            };
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind each row's upload button's disablity state to different model inside $scope, one way for doing that is to hold each row disablity state in it self,so you need to change tests array to an object like this:

```
$scope.tests = [{name:"A",disabled:1}, {name:"B",disabled:1}, {name:"C",disabled:1}]
```

`disabled` now holds the state of upload button disability for each row.
by changing tests this way, you'll need to change your code like bellow to achieve what you are looking for:

```
<table>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="test in tests ">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{test.name}}</td>
    <td style="color:red"> pending</td>
    <td><font size="2" color="red"></font>
       <select ng-model="checkStatus" ng-init="checkStatus='NotDone'"
       ng-options="status.sta as status.name for status in status"
       ng-change="changePayStatus(checkStatus,test)"></select>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-2">
      <p>
           <button type="button" ng-show="!pictureEditor" ng-click="pictureEditor = true"
            ng-disabled="test.disabled" class="btn-primary btn-u-xs">Upload </button>
         ...
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

**Edited:** As you can see in the HTML,I'm passing `test` object that I've got from `ng-repeat` to `changePayStatus` method, while `test` is member of `tests` and we've got `tests` from the scope, therefore `test` it self is from the scope and angular will handle changes on it,in views you can pass models that you've got from scope, to controller again and angular handles the rest.
so you also need to change controller like this:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.tests = [{name:"A",disabled:1}, {name:"B",disabled:1}, {name:"C",disabled:1}] 
     $scope.status = [{name :"Done", sta : 1}, {name : "NotDone", sta : 0}];
     $scope.changePayStatus = function(status,testItem) {
         console.log(status);
         if(status == 1) {
            testItem.disabled= 0;
         }
         else if(status == 0) {
            testItem.disabled= 1;

         }
     };
});
```

**An edited working sample can be found [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/m55ow6re/24/)**

hope that helps.

Comment: thanks took some time to understand but I did not get how you are able to change the value in  testItem.sta = 0; without using $scope.

Comment: @sacDahal,I'm  sorry for my bad English,but I updated the answer for your question, hope that helps you.